# xml2js not writing as expected

Tags: node.js, json, xml, xml2js

Given this XML layout:

```
<config>
  <Nightly>
    <VersionNumber>1.10.0</VersionNumber>
  </Nightly>
</config>
```

And this code ([based on this article](https://attacomsian.com/blog/nodjs-edit-xml-file)):

```
NewVersionNumber = '1.10.1';

fs.readFile("../config.xml", "utf-8", (err, data) => {

xml2js.parseString(data, (err, result) => {
    result.config.Nightly.VersionNumber = NewVersionNumber;

    const builder = new xml2js.Builder();
    const xml = builder.buildObject(result);

    fs.writeFile('../config.xml', xml, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });
});
```

I'm getting this result:

```
<config>
  <Nightly>
    <VersionNumber>1.10.0</VersionNumber>
  </Nightly>
  <Nightly>1.10.1</Nightly>
</config>
```

What am I doing wrong?  The goal is for it to *update* the `config.Nightly.VersionNumber` value.

Comment: I also noticed subsequent updates just *append*. This is not desired.  The code was working fine before I added the "Nightly" sub element, it was updating `config.VersionNumber` as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `explicitArray:false` params:

```
xml2js.parseString(data, {explicitArray:false}, (err, result) => {
```

see here:

> explicitArray (default: true): Always put child nodes in an array if
> true; otherwise an array is created only if there is more than one.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js#options

Comment: Thank you. Seems weird that this isn't the default behavior to me. "Array is created only if there is more than one" sounds a bit duh.

Comment: @THEJOATMON first thought was that it's a default parsers thing, but looks like not: https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/blob/1832e0b6b2de30a5e326d1cf21708cd32305a538/src/parser.coffee#L56. So I guess it depends. For example, if everything is of the same type, then there is no need for extra type check maybe.. or similar..

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the issue by simply adding `[0]` to each element:

```
result.config.Nightly[0].AppName[0] = message.AppName;
result.config.Nightly[0].VersionNumber[0] = message.VersionNumber;
result.config.Nightly[0].Branch[0] = message.Branch;
```

I'm posting this as an answer because it fixed it, but I'd love to see other answers or explanations.